# External Bluetooth Microphone - iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones with a microphone and I want to use the microphone on the Bluetooth headphones to record some audio into an audio recording app on the iPad. I have tried multiple apps so this isn't the problem.

My problem is the iPad won't pick up the audio from the microphone on the Bluetooth headphone. I know that the audio from the microphone can be picked up by the iPad as there is an option when you are face-timing to change the input source.

How can I change the input for the audio in the iPad settings?

Answer (score 1):

I am in a nearly identical situation as you. I have been manically searching for this answer for the past two days, finding little. But here is what little I've found:

The Bluetooth mic is used during phone calls, facetime, and speech-to-text. It is not used for anything related to recording, as if the software is only ok with using that input if the evidence is destroyed immediately, if no record is kept. Wired headphones that have mics built-in will work for recordings, but for some reason the Bluetooth headsets are treated differently. This is true for my iPad mini and for my Android phone.

The most plausible theory I've heard is that there might be some safety regulation that is responsible. Like the government thinks it would be too easy to eavesdrop on people through their headsets if they didn't make these restrictions. But that is just speculation.

Anyway, I hope I was able to tell you something you didn't already know. I will be anxiously monitoring your post to see if someone who knows more than me shares new information. Good luck!!